# How to disable very next textarea on change of textbox in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

There are multiple Textbox and Textarea in my code.

I have kept kid class common in all textboxes.

What i expect is when user enter any value, the VERY NEXT TEXTAREA should get disabled. Following is structure

```
<div>
<div>
    <input type="text" class="kid" value="" name="kid" id="kid" />
</div>
<div>
    <div></div>
    <div>
        <textarea cols="30" rows="2" name="comment" id="comment">  </textarea>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

JQuery Code which is not working is:

```
var a = {
init: function () {
    $(".kid").on("change keyup paste", function () {
        if ($(this).val() != "") {
            $(this).next().attr("disabled", true);
        } else {
            $(this).next().attr("disabled", false);
        }
    });
}
};
$(document).ready(a.init());
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0f6vp938/

Answer (score 1):

```js
var a = {
    init: function () {
        $(".kid").on("change keyup input", function () {
            if ($(this).val() != "") {
                $(this).parent().next().find('textarea').prop("disabled", true);
            } else {
                $(this).parent().next().find('textarea').prop("disabled", false);
            }
        });
    }
};
$(document).ready(a.init());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" class="kid" value="" name="kid" id="kid" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <div></div>
        <div>
            <textarea cols="30" rows="2" name="comment" id="comment"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `prop()` instead of `attr()`:

```
var a = {
    init: function () {
        $(".kid").on("change keyup paste", function () {
            if ($(this).val() != "") {
                $("#comment").prop("disabled", true);
            } else {
                $("#comment").prop("disabled", false);
            }
        });
    }
};
$(document).ready(a.init());
```

**Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0f6vp938/5/**

Comment: Not working because the next selector is wrong in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this perhaps?

```
    var a = {
    init: function () {
        $(".kid").on("change keyup paste", function () {
            var $inp = $(this);
            var v = $inp.val().trim();

            if (v != "") {
                $inp.parent('div').parent('div').find('textarea').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
            } else {
                $inp.parent('div').parent('div').find('textarea').prop('disabled', false);
            }

        });
    }
    };
    $(document).ready(a.init());
```

Answer (score 0):

In the fiddle you have provided, the TEXTAREA is not really next to the INPUT tag.

Keep them together and you are through.

```html
<div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" class="kid" value="" name="kid" id="kid" />
        <textarea cols="30" rows="2" name="comment" id="comment"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0f6vp938/1/).

If you do not want to keep them together like this, then you should use the ID or CLASS of the TEXTAREA you want to disable

HTML:

```html
<div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" class="kid" value="" name="kid" id="kid" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <div></div>
        <div>
            <textarea cols="30" rows="2" name="comment" id="comment"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```js
var a = {
    init: function () {
        $(".kid").on("change keyup paste", function () {
   if ($(this).val() != "") {
                $('#comment').attr("disabled", true);
            } else {
                $('#comment').attr("disabled", false);
            }
        });
    }
};
$(document).ready(a.init());
```

as shown in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0f6vp938/3/).